# copy entire self executable to memory c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have an c++ executable, I concatenated the last part of it, with an image.
Would like to load the entire executable to memory, then break the concatenated image into a unsigned char * to be loaded, inside the same executable.

Suppose the executable itself has a size of 47104 and the image has a size of 13216.
So concatening these two, the executable would be around 60320 (47104 + 13216).
I was thinking about :

```
unsigned char * entireExe;
unsigned char * img;

memcpy(entireExe, how to load the entire executable to memory???, 60320);
memcpy(img, entireExe + 47104, 13216);
displayImage(img); // using any method available (opencv/poco/devilIL/opengl,etc)
```

Comment: Have you considered simply declaring `unsigned char img[]={ ... }`, containing the image in question, and simply forget about messing around with operating system-specific issues, and just using plain, standard, C++?

Comment: Or why not simply use standard I/O to open the file, seek to the image data, and then read it?

Comment: Hello Sam,

The reaosn I don't want to take that route is for securiy reasons, the asset is actually encrypted.

Comment: So? Nothing stops you from including the *encrypted* data in that array.

Comment: Yes, but considering that there several of those files, not just one, I tried to add just a few inside a array and had heap issues.

Comment: Another alternative, on Windows, is to use a *resource* file to include the raw binary blob, and use Windows functions to extract it.

Comment: You totally right! But I would love a cross platform solution. I am, asking here as my last hope, otherwise I will take your advice.

Comment: And a last alternative: Just dont embed binary data, and use an installer to copy the files to the system. Makes it *much* easier to handle multiple files, as they really are files. Or perhaps use a zip-archive (or similar) to include the data files.

Comment: Thanks Dude, again, you right. But I am pretty sure there is a way to learn how I can achive my question.

Comment: A "cross platform solution" would be what I described. Works with every C++ compiler. In fact, your attempted solution is probably as far from cross platform as possible. You do realize, for example, that there is no such thing as an "entireEXE" on Linux, which doesn't use exe files, but rather uses a completely different binary format.

Comment: No doubt Sam, but I would like to learn how to work this out using memory only (if possible).
But the entireEXE is a array of unsigned char, cross platform right ? As well, as memcpy.

Comment: Where do you think this `unsigned char` array would wind up in, if not "memory only"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not load a DLL into memory and use its address space to hold the image information? It should allocate enough space to do whatever you need to do. Or you could display the image inside of a window created by the DLL if you want. If you are trying to edit the executable itself, I would suggest using IDA or any other reverse engineer tool to look at it's PE struct/memory pages and going from there.

This is a good resource:
https://github.com/67-6f-64/Firefly/blob/master/Firefly%20Library/pe_structs.hpp

Comment: Hey Rodney! Yes!! That is what I was thinking, I will look into to it right now!